# Convert JPanel to binary array

Tags: java

I programmed something like paint. I have JPanel and I can draw on it.I'm using only black line. I wanna convert it to binary array, where 1 is when pixel is black, 0 when is white (background). It's possible? How to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113897/how-do-i-get-the-image-paint-paintcomponent-generates should help you getting started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, create a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) with the same dimensions as your JPanel and [paint the panel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) to the image.  Then you can iterate over the image raster to get the sequence of pixel color values corresponding to black and white.  For example

```java
// Paint the JPanel to a BufferedImage.
Dimension size = jpanel.getSize();
int imageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
BufferedImage image = BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, imageType);
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
jpanel.paint(g2);

// Now iterate the image in row-major order to test its pixel colors.
for (int y=0; y<size.height; y++) {
  for (int x=0; ix<size.width; x++) {
    int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
    if (pixel == 0xFF000000) {
      // Black (assuming no transparency).
    } else if (pixel == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
      // White (assuming no transparency).
    } else {
      // Some other color...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See also [ComponentImageCapture.java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe/5853992#5853992).